# How to get IP address Jetty is running on

Tags: jetty, cometd

I'm developing Spring MVC cluster website and emulating a cluster on one developer machine, running several instances of **Jetty 9.2.2** on different local addresses:

127.0.0.10

127.0.0.11

127.0.0.12

and so on. To use CometD clustering solution, I need to know at runtime IP address of Jetty server, **which is currently serving** this particular runtime. I mean, would it be 127.0.0.10, or 127.0.0.12. I set this parameter in start.ini:

```
jetty.host=127.0.0.N
```

where N is different for every of 5 instances.

So, how do I know it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The CometD Oort cluster supports three modes of discovering other nodes: automatic, static and manual.

The automatic way is based on multicast, so if you have multicast working on the hosts the problem should be solved.

With the static way, you just need one "well known" server to be up and running, and point all other nodes to that "well known" server.

With the manual way, you can use other discovery mechanisms (for example, lookup `jetty.host` in the System properties) and initialize the Oort instances with the discovered values.

It is all explained in the [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_oort).

Comment: First of all, thank you and your company for developing CometD and Jetty. Now related to question: yes, but aren't I supposed to explicitly specify oort.url parameter, which is required for all discovery strategies? "The unique URL of the Bayeux server associated to the Oort comet". I'm trying to avoid hardcoding this for each node, so I could use one app.war on each node so each node could figure out its address:port by itself. After that, automatic discovery is the way, but to make 

oort = new Oort(bayeuxServer(), "http://address:port/cometd");

i need to know address:port.

Comment: Can you please add a feature request at http://bugs.cometd.org ? Basically what you want is to be able to dynamically configure CometD properties so that you don't have to hardcode them in the war, but possibly read them externally. See also https://github.com/cometd/cometd/pull/19. Feel free to comment there with your specific use case. I'm thinking this is probably going to make it for the next CometD release. Thanks !